# "Item has incomplete type" при создании template

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть следующий код:

```
template<typename Item>
class Queue{
    enum{QUEUE_SIZE=10};
    static int s_int_queue_elem_counter;
    Item item;
    Queue* next;
  public:
    explicit Queue():item(item){}
    explicit Queue(const Item& _item):item(_item){}
    void addQueue(const Item&);
};
```

Возникает ошибка

> Queue::item has incomplete type.

Почему?

Comment: Видимо в момент инстанцирования Item не является "полностью описанным" типом, компилятор не знает какой именно класс создать.
Приведите код класса и код точки инстанцирования.

Comment: инстанциируется в main.cpp путем вызова Queue<int> A;

Comment: Какой компилятор? GCC (http://ideone.com/fKRSQ) и VS2008 компилируют без ошибок.

Comment: MinGW ver 10

Comment: MinGW не компилятор, какой версии там g++.exe ?

Comment: Version 4.4.1

Comment: На gcc-4.5.1 тоже собирается http://ideone.com/CpWBT
Попробуйте на ideone полностью код собрать, если там 1 файл

Comment: У меня возникает смутное подозрение, что ошибка происходит не в определении шаблона, а в момент его инстанциирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так а каким item ты инициализируешь item в дефолтном конструкторе ??? ...:item(item) что это за бред ?! хотябы так :item((Item)0);

```
    template<typename Item>
    class Queue {
            enum{QUEUE_SIZE=10};
            static int s_int_queue_elem_counter;
            Item item;
            Queue* next;

        public:

            explicit Queue():item((Item)0) {} 
            //Тут скорее всего приведет к ошибке, 
            //если вы в качестве Item укажите класс.
            //Так что лучьше этот конструктор убрать.
            //Ключевое слово explicit тут тоже лишнее.

            explicit Queue(const Item& _item):item(_item) {}
            void addQueue(const Item& var) { item += var; };
    };

    int main()
    {
        Queue<int> A;
        Queue<int> B(1);
        A.addQueue(2);
        return 0;
    }
```

#### Ваш код (но рабочий):

```
    template<typename Item>
    class Queue {
            enum{QUEUE_SIZE=10};
            static int s_int_queue_elem_counter;
            Item item;
            Queue* next;

        public:                 
            explicit Queue(const Item& _item) : item(_item) {}
            void addQueue(const Item& var);
    };
```

Comment: (Item)0
 
Очень плохо. А если в качестве аргумента шаблона будет использоваться какой-нибудь тип вроде класса? Что получится?

Comment: По этому я и написал "хотябы(для этого случая)", т.е. он явно хотел этот item чем то инициализировать, а чем бы вы его инициализировали ?! т.е. там был еще метод addQueue правда пустой, я добавил что то не очень хорошее "item += var;" при котором инициализировать хоть чем то в любом случае надо! а раз его в любом случае надо инициализировать, то нужно было бы дефолтный конструктор убрать, я его оставил намеренно что бы было видно "Почему возникает ошибка".
Естественно тут нужно убрать или это дурацкий конструктор или template...
Но да, спасибо!:) Надо было сразу это указать=)

Comment: Уж лучше ничем.

     item()

Во всяком случае, это будет работать для простых типов и для тех, у которых определен дефолтный конструктор. Для иных нужно делать специализацию шаблона.

Comment: Хотя общая идея вашего ответа правильная. item(item) совсем никуда не годится.

Comment: Ну да, а про инициализацию я же и говорю, что если конструктор оставить (и ничем его не инициализировать) то item += var; будет весьма непредсказуемым, и то, опять же он вообще будет только для тех Item у которых оператор += определен...

Comment: А можно еще маленький вопрос: Ведь explicit задавать в конструкторе без параметров или с более чем с одним параметром, бессмысленно ? т.е. тут  explicit Queue(){} он не нужен ?!

Comment: @lirik90 Да, вы правы. `explicit` имеет смысл только в конструкторе с одним параметром, чтобы запретить неявные преобразования типов.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. класс `Queue` шаблонный, то конструкция вида `Queue* next`, вообще говоря, ошибочная - не указан шаблонный параметр, и указатель на какой именно тип создавать компилятор сам не решит. Исправьте на `Queue<Item>* next`.